# Передать значение переменной из PHP в JS

Tags: jquery, wordpress

В цикле мы объявляем переменные `$first_image` и `$second_image` и присваиваем значения, в данном случае значением переменных являются ссылки на изображения. Для блока с классом `.slide-item` мы задаем `background-image` и передаем туда значение переменной `$first_image`.

Внимание вопрос:

Как правильно передать значение переменной `$first_image` в событие `afterChange` и `$second_image` в `beforeChange`, где мы указываем css свойства `background-image`?

```
<div id="slider">

<?php

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'slider',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'orderby' => 'name'
    );
    
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) { $query->the_post();

        $first_image = get_field( '1st_image');
        $second_image = get_field( '2nd_image');

?>

    <div class="slide-item" style="background-image:url('<?php echo $first_image; ?>')"></div>

<?php } ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

</div>
```

Пример JS

```
$("#slider").slick({
  dots: true,
  arrows: true,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 10000,
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1
});

$("#slider").on("afterChange", function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.slide-item').css("background-image","url('https://dummyimage.com/1920x900/ccc/fff.jpg')");
  }, 5000);
});

$("#slider").on("beforeChange", function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
  $(".slide-item").css("background-image","url('https://dummyimage.com/1920x900/555/fff.jpg')");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Если правильно понял вопрос, то вставить их в код на странице

```
$("#slider").on("afterChange", function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.slide-item').css("background-image","url('<? echo $first_image ?>')");
    }, 5000);
});
    
$("#slider").on("beforeChange", function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
    $(".slide-item").css("background-image","url('<? echo $second_image ?>')");
});
```

Comment: если я вставлю этот JS в блок `#slider`, то slick добавит его как элемент слайдера, а если вынесу из блока, тогда значения переменных будут пустыми

Comment: вернее в переменные попадут значения последнего слайда